# Select n child with react material ui makeStyle

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React and Material UI and i'm currently trying to use the nth-child selector with the MUI makeStyle function but it doesn't work as expected, here are some screenshots :

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see I would like to set a background color to every even children but every children's background is actually colored.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

look for the class, create a css file and that's it, that's how it worked for me in some components.
example

```
.Mui-checked{
    color:$primary !important;
}
.MuiFormControlLabel-label{
    color:$tertiary !important;
}
.Mui-focused{
    color:$tertiary !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok my bad I was applying style to container and not to all elements inside, stupid mistake